# How to implement order by in with string which contain alphabet and number

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Table Name is `itemmaster`

I have below data

```
ItemDesc  ParentID
--------  --------
1005      1
A-105     1
A-106     1
A-101     1
1001      1
B-105     2
B-106     2
B-101     2
101       2
```

and I want to order by and get a result like

```
ItemDesc
--------
A-101
A-105
A-106
1001
1005
B-101
B-105
B-106
101
```

I m trying with

```
  ORDER BY  `itemmaster`.`ParentItemId` ASC
```

so what's orderby query for above code

Comment: _so what's orderby query for above code?_ What queries have "you" been trying?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Don’t just ask for someone to give you “the code” - show what you have tried, tell us what your research turned up so far, describe what the specific problem is you where left with after that. Also, give a proper description of _how_ you want those values to be sorted, don’t just give an example without any further explanation.

Comment: The order by for this is gonna be tricky.. very tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This query. This is working fine from my side.

```
SELECT `ItemDesc` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `ParentID` ASC, `ItemDesc` * 1, `ItemDesc` ASC
```

OutPut:

```
ItemDesc
A-101
A-105
A-106
1001
1005
B-101
B-105
B-106
101
```

Comment: the result is the same even if I remove [itemmaster.ItemDesc * 1]

Comment: Please check when you remove the result will be different. Like 1001
1005
A-101
A-105
A-106
101
B-101
B-105
B-106. I have tested first this in my query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to order in 3 different steps:

1. First by the `ParentID`;
2. Then you want the textual fields before the numbers of the `ItemDesc` field;
3. Then you want the `ItemDesc` values alphabetically / numerically ascending.

In an order by, that would look something like:

```
ORDER BY
    `ParentID`,
    IF(`ItemDesc` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$', 1, 0),    # If numerical then 1 as that comes after 0
    `ItemDesc`
```

Ascending `ASC` is the default so I have left that out for all 3.